# drag or move image inside a canvas using touchmove in HTML5 for touch devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cross-platform

I'm creating a HTML5 game which can be made to run on Android also. I went through few articles and didn't get the solution yet. I have a image which i'm generating through javascript and I want to move this image using touchmove so that I can run it in my Android device. This is the code:

```
    gameCanvas.addEventListener("touchmove", touchXY, true);
function touchXY(e) {
        if (!e)
            var e = event;
        e.preventDefault();
        avatarX = e.targetTouches[0].pageX - gameCanvas.offsetLeft;
        avatarY = e.targetTouches[0].pageY - gameCanvas.offsetTop;

    }
```

This is not working. I got this code from https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/AddingMouseandTouchControlstoCanvas/AddingMouseandTouchControlstoCanvas.html

And this is my canvas:

```
<canvas id="gameCanvas" onclick="setUpGame();" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

This is my image:

```
avatarImage.src = "img/avatar.png";

gameCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(avatarImage, Math.random() * 100, Math.random() * 100);
```

I just want to move the image inside the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a full example, hopefully it's not too verbose.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id='canvas' width='512' height='512'></canvas>
    <script>
      var c=document.getElementById('canvas'),
          ctx=c.getContext('2d'),
          activeBox='none',
          //populate the map with objects
          box=[
            {
              x:256,
              y:128,
              width:32,
              height:64
            },
            {
              x:128,
              y:64,
              width:64,
              height:64
            },
            {
              x:32,
              y:32,
              width:32,
              height:32
            },
          ];

      function draw(){
        //clear the screen, draw population
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
        for(var i=0;i<box.length;i++){
          ctx.fillRect(box[i].x,box[i].y,box[i].width,box[i].height);
        }
        //repeat at 60fps if possible, pause if window looses focus
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
      }

      function startTouch(e){
        //this makes it easier to write control flow later and keeps XY relative to canvas
        var xTouch=e.touches[0].pageX-c.offsetLeft,
            yTouch=e.touches[0].pageY-c.offsetTop;

        //its best to go through this loop in touchstart, because it only happens once per touch
        for(var i=0;i<box.length;i++){
          if(xTouch>box[i].x&&xTouch<box[i].x+box[i].width){
            if(yTouch>box[i].y&&yTouch<box[i].y+box[i].height){
              activeBox=i;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      function moveTouch(e){
        //grab a box by the center
        if(activeBox!='none'){
          box[activeBox].x=e.changedTouches[0].pageX-box[activeBox].width/2;
          box[activeBox].y=e.changedTouches[0].pageY-box[activeBox].height/2;
        }
      }

      function endTouch(){
        //clear active so that dragging empty space wont move the last active box
        activeBox='none';
      }

      canvas.addEventListener('touchstart',startTouch);
      canvas.addEventListener('touchmove',moveTouch);
      canvas.addEventListener('touchend',endTouch);
      window.addEventListener('load',draw);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I used fillRect for simplicity, but if you want to replace it with drawImage you'll need to create a new element for each and add a source property to the box object array. Here's a partial example.

```
//you need a new one of these for every image
var img=new Image();
    img.src='http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png';
var box={
      source:img,
      x:Math.floor((Math.random()*256)+1),
      y:Math.floor((Math.random()*256)+1)
    };
//make sure the image doesnt load before the script
window.onload=function(){
  ctx.drawImage(img,box.x,box.y);
}
```